# OpenGL program not working as expected even after everything is fine

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, opengl

Below is what I am using and working with:

- Operating System - Windows 7 64Bit
- IDE - Visual studio 2010 professional
- Working on OpenGL with the basic lib files that are already present in visual studio i.e "opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" and "gl.h" "glu.h"

Below is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
//
// GLSAMPLE.CPP
//  by Blaine Hodge
//

// Includes

#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
// Function Declarations

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hWnd, HDC * hDC, HGLRC * hRC);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND hWnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC);

// WinMain

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASS wc;
HWND hWnd;
HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
MSG msg;
BOOL quit = FALSE;
float theta = 0.0f;

// register window class
wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( BLACK_BRUSH );
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
RegisterClass( &wc );

// create main window
hWnd = CreateWindow( 
    "GLSample", "OpenGL Sample", 
    WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
    0, 0, 256, 256,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

// enable OpenGL for the window
EnableOpenGL( hWnd, &hDC, &hRC );

// program main loop
while ( !quit )
{

    // check for messages
    if ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE )  )
    {

        // handle or dispatch messages
        if ( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) 
        {
            quit = TRUE;
        } 
        else 
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }

    } 
    else 
    {

        // OpenGL animation code goes here

        glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef( theta, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
        glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex2f( 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex2f( 0.87f, -0.5f );
        glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex2f( -0.87f, -0.5f );
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        SwapBuffers( hDC );

        theta += 1.0f;

    }

}

// shutdown OpenGL
DisableOpenGL( hWnd, hDC, hRC );

// destroy the window explicitly
DestroyWindow( hWnd );

return msg.wParam;

}

// Window Procedure

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

switch (message)
{

case WM_CREATE:
    return 0;

case WM_CLOSE:
    PostQuitMessage( 0 );
    return 0;

case WM_DESTROY:
    return 0;

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch ( wParam )
    {

    case VK_ESCAPE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    }
    return 0;

default:
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );

}

}

// Enable OpenGL

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hWnd, HDC * hDC, HGLRC * hRC)
{
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
int format;

// get the device context (DC)
*hDC = GetDC( hWnd );

// set the pixel format for the DC
ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 24;
pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
format = ChoosePixelFormat( *hDC, &pfd );
SetPixelFormat( *hDC, format, &pfd );

// create and enable the render context (RC)
*hRC = wglCreateContext( *hDC );
wglMakeCurrent( *hDC, *hRC );

}

// Disable OpenGL

void DisableOpenGL(HWND hWnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );
wglDeleteContext( hRC );
ReleaseDC( hWnd, hDC );
}
```

Below is the link for expected output:

- http://www.nullterminator.net/glsample.gif

What I am getting on execution:

- A blank black console screen.

Important notes:

- Added opengl32.lib, glu32.lib in input section in project properties.
- Drivers are updated

So can anyone tell me that what is wrong here. And one more thing that I have downloaded this code, not written it myself, here is the link for it http://www.nullterminator.net/opengl32.html

Comment: Hi,  did you get your code from the link towards the bottom of the page at http://www.nullterminator.net/glsample.zip ?  Also what project type have you created?

Comment: yes I have downloaded it from the link, I created a win32 project

Comment: What is `ChoosePixelFormat()` returning?

Answer (score 0):

I see no projection/orthographic matrix in your code. You have to specify a camera for your scene. As the fixed function pipeline is deprecated i don't know the exact commands for this. I think its `gluPerspecive`.

#### See:

http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

Comment: Actually the program is throwing no errors and no warnings at all

Comment: This is the first time i am coding with opengl.

Comment: @code OpenGL errors are not thrown. You need to check for errors with this function: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml